# FM transmitter, aux-in adapter, or car deck for car audio? help please. :)

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I have a Honda Civic 2005, and it just has the stock radio. I'm wanting to add audio input into my car, as it can only play CD's and the radio. I'm not sure what option to get and I've been looking for one and I can't deduce which one is best to have. So far, I've looked at a FM transmitter, an aux-in adapter for the stock radio, and just to buy a new/used car deck that supports bluetooth, aux, and USB. Not sure if there are more options that may be better, but I would appreciate the help/feedback. Also, if you do recommend something, as I am mechanically challenged, I would appreciate a manual on how to install the device and if it would be compatible with the Honda Civic.

Answer (score 1):

all 3 are valid options. 
I do think this is a personal preference sort of decision.

ask yourself what device(s) you want to connect.
ask yourself how much you want to spend.

if looking to save $ and assuming your head unit aux in is a 1/8" trs (had phone jack), and assuming your drive has the same, this is a very easy cheap option.

if $ is not an issue or you don't have a device with any out put connector or you mention blutooth and want arguably the most convenient option, the switching out the head unit is the way to go...

in this day and age I think the FM transmitter is an antiquated and least convenient method.

not sure anyone could give u an answer here...
just their own opinions.

Answer (score 1):

So, tried 2 of the three - FM transmitter works fine until you get to an area that is using the frequency you chose. Did look at aux-in adaptor but decided to replace unit. Fitting one is easier now as the car will have a manufacturer fitted plug (in 2005 most cars had them...) and you can order the adaptor (and the plastic surround for fitting) for your car and the unit you choose so it is really plug and play.